# Getting File not found error" with zipfile module python

Tags: python, python-3.x, long-path

```
  File "import.py", line 64, in unzip
  File "zipfile.py", line 1647, in extractall
  File "zipfile.py", line 1701, in _extract_member
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Getting this error for a file while unzipping, The character length for the entire path is 271 characters. Can this be due to long path >? Longpath value is 1 in the registry for Longpathenabled variable.

Comment: That's the entire message? It doesn't tell you the file path where it found "No such file or directory"? As an aside, `import.py` is probably not a great name for your source file (what if some other part of the code wanted to import it?)

Comment: It tells about the path also but I didn't wanted to keep it here so just mentioned that its 270 characters long.  so Can this be due to long path? The strange thing is it's failing on one of the windows node in the other one its working fine

Comment: It could be that a malicious zip file is trying to drop its file in a place where it shouldn't have access, or above the file system root, etc. At any rate it would help if you can manage to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - if it depends on the zip file, maybe you can find a process that creates a zip file that exhibits the problem.

Comment: any solution on this so far? Can we somehow rename the file simultaneously with the extraction so it doesn't complain for the long path? I am facing the same issue when the folder is a OneDrive folder.